# Another resource to display the list

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a table "orders" with reference to another one.
I made sql view "v_orders" with fields to display from both tables.

Is that any way to tell react-admin Resource that I want to display lists of items from my view, but create and edit form take resource from the base table?

Now I have: `<Resource name={"orders"} options={{ label: "Orders" }} key={"orders"} {...modelViews(Orders)} />`

What i want: `<Resource name={"orders"} listResourse={"v_orders"} options={{ label: "Orders" }} key={"orders"} {...modelViews(Orders)} />`

Comment: What is your backend and can't you handle this there?

Answer (score 0):

React-admin doesn't provide a way to do what you want. It takes the opposite approach: entities from the List and Edit views MUST share the same schema, because react-admin stores them both in a shared store.

I suggest you create two Resource, and use a custom Create and Edit button to link from the List of the first resource to the create and edit forms of the second resource.

```
<Resource name="orders" list={modelViews(Orders).list} />
<Resource name="v_orders" create={modelViews(Orders).create} edit={modelViews(Orders).edit} />
```